# odoo12: set different images for different screen sizes

Tags: image, mobile, odoo, odoo-12

I'm new to developing for Odoo 12 and want to know how to set different images for mobile and non-mobile divices.

In Odoo 10 (previous edition) I could use the classes 'visible-md, visible-lg, visible-sm, and visible-xs' to control this.  But this has been deprecated, how do I do this in Odoo 12?

Answer (score 0):

Odoo 12 use Bootstrap 4.

so use following class to make your webpage responsive.

The Bootstrap 4 grid system has five classes:

```
.col- (extra small devices - screen width less than 576px)
.col-sm- (small devices - screen width equal to or greater than 576px)
.col-md- (medium devices - screen width equal to or greater than 768px)
.col-lg- (large devices - screen width equal to or greater than 992px)
.col-xl- (xlarge devices - screen width equal to or greater than 1200px)
```

Comment: so I would use `class="col-sm col-md"`?